# How to convert kendo filter object to string

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When applied filter in kendo grid i am getting filter as object like below

```
filter :  { filters : [], logic : "and"}
```

But in some kendo examples filter is displaying like

```
   filter : "producatname~eq~test"
```

How to change filter from object to string

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are writing JavaScript code in a web page and want to convert the filter data to a string suitable for sending or saving, you can use [`transport.parameterMap`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap) to convert filters to a string.

```
const grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
const parameterMap = grid.dataSource.transport.parameterMap;
const filterString = parameterMap({filter: grid.dataSource.filter()}).filter
```

On the MVC side you can then use `Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.FilterDescriptorFactory.Create(string)` to parse the string.

Comment: Brilliantly clear example! I couldn't decipher much from the documentation.